# How we can create BaseActivity and BaseFragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to programming. Can anyone help me, to create the BaseActivity and BaseFragment in Kotlin with use the same in child classes. I do Google but can't clear the topic in my mind. I am sharing source code in below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_Container">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="5dp" />
```

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var lastFragmentName:String = ""
    var toolbar: Toolbar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getLayoutResource())
        configureToolbar()
    }

    protected abstract fun backStackChangeListener(backStackCount: Int)

    protected abstract fun getLayoutResource(): Int

    open fun configureToolbar(){
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        if (toolbar != null){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener())

            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
            supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
            fragmentTransaction.add(
                R.id.fragment_Container,
                fragment,
                fragment.javaClass.simpleName
            )
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }

    fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener())

            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
            supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
            fragmentTransaction.replace(
                R.id.fragment_Container,
                fragment,
                fragment.javaClass.simpleName
            )
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }

    fun removeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
            fragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }

    fun removeTopFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }

    private fun getListener(): FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
        return FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            if (fragmentManager != null) {
                backStackChangeListener(getBackStackCount())
                val currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_Container) as BaseFragment
                if (currentFragment != null && !lastFragmentName.equals(currentFragment.javaClass.simpleName)) {
                    lastFragmentName = currentFragment.javaClass.simpleName
                    currentFragment.onResume()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getBackStackCount(): Int {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        return fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    abstract fun getTitle(): Int

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        (activity as BaseActivity).replaceFragment(fragment)
    }

    private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        (activity as BaseFragment).addFragment(fragment)
    }

    private fun removeTopFragment(){
        (activity as BaseFragment).removeTopFragment()
    }

    private fun setTitle(resId: Int){
        activity?.setTitle(resId)
    }

    private fun setTitle(title:String){
        activity?.setTitle(title)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? Please be more specific so that we can help you.

Comment: I want to CommonActivity extends DerivedActivity and CommonFragment extends DerivedFragment.